# jboss-eap-6 support for postgres 9.6 BDR

Tags: jboss-eap-6, postgresql-9.6

Does Jboss EAP 6.1 support the postgres version 9.6 with BDR?

According to jboss site it supports upto postgres 9.3.
I also want to know if there will be any issues on going for postgres 9.6 BDR.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat normally provides the list of tested DB configurations, not the list of supported DBs.

Normally if the underlying JDBC driver is compatible with both JDK and DB, then it should work without much issue.

The General thumb rule is JDK should compatible or supported for both EAP and JDBC driver used and JDBC driver should be compatible with Database used.

If you have RedHat subscription you can directly raise a support ticket and check.